# fixunknows on nftool GUI matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, neural-network

I am using the nftool GUI to set up a regression neural network.

My database has various NaN (missing values). When I run the GUI, everything seems to go right. It gives me the performance and the regression graph.

I read that by line code you can add a processFcn named 'fixunknowns' to the network.

My question is: In the GUI, is the neural network making the fixunknows? How the GUI is procesing this NaN?
When I generate the script, the fixunknows function does not appear.

I wonder if it is only possible to treat this NaN values on line code? Or... perhaps the GUI implements the fixnknowns automatically?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the end of nftool, click 'advanced script'. This script will repeat exactly what you have done in `nftool`. In it you will see

```
% Choose Input and Output Pre/Post-Processing Functions
% For a list of all processing functions type: help nnprocess
net.input.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};
net.output.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};
```

This would indicate that `fixunknowns` is not run, (unless it is called by a function we can't see in this script). So you can add this line

```
net.input.processFcns = {'fixunknowns'};
```

Note that you should not run `fixunknowns` on the output. If there are NaNs in the output, delete the entire row/sample.

If you make a change in the GUI, you will have to add the fixunknowns each time.